# strptime( ) function in [R] to manipulate date/time class

Tags: r, time-series

So i'm working with a simple data set wanting to plot day x frequency

the date is given in a human-readable format of

```
> head(gb.day)
[1] Sep 12, 2011 11:59 PM Sep 12, 2011 11:59 PM Sep 12, 2011 11:58 PM
[4] Sep 12, 2011 11:56 PM Sep 12, 2011 11:55 PM Sep 12, 2011 11:55 PM
644 Levels: Sep 12, 2011 01:09 PM Sep 12, 2011 01:10 PM ... Sep 12, 2011 11:59 PM
```

and is read as a factor.

I'm trying to convert it into a date via the strptime( ) function in [R] and am running into problems

```
> strptime(gb.day,"%b %d %Y %l %p")
```

I thought would be the correct parameters but is returning NAs
Are my parameters correct?

Are there any other suggestions to accomplish this simple hassle

Comment: OP here, just realized it might be due to the commas in the data

Comment: Solved my own problem. had to gsub out the commas, and the time parameter wasn't the right one. should have been as.Date(gbday.no.commas,format="%b %d %Y %R %p")

Answer (score 5):

You can also add the comma in the `strptime()` format:

```
R> var <- "Sep 12, 2011 11:59 PM"
R> strptime(var, "%b %d, %Y %I:%M %p")
[1] "2011-09-12 23:59:00"
R>
```

Apart from that, your problem may have the use of factor encoding.  Also try

```
R> strptime( as.character(gb.day) ,"%b %d, %Y %I:%M %p")
```

Lastly, you may have inadvertently swapped a '1' (digit one) or an 'I' (uppercase i).

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime

start_time = datetime.strptime(datetime.now(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```